# Display contents of the file searched by grep or find command

Tags: shell, grep, find, cat

I have lots of directories in a certain directory and I am trying to find a specific file present in there. I used grep command recursively and was able to locate the file being present in there, but I don't know where it is present exactly. So, how can I use cat on that file to display the contents of that file?

PS- I finally got it. I was doing it all wrong. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: `grep` recursive should print the file path by default. What options did you use?

Comment: you tagged `find`; did you use `find` in combination with `grep` somehow? How?

Comment: You wrote "I used grep command recursively and was able to locate the file being present in there". To make it more clear what you want, I suggest to [edit] your question and show the command(s) you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below command

```
find  path -type f -iname "filename" -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% what you want, but consider the following:

```
grep -Rl pattern | xargs cat
```

`grep -l` will print only the file location relative to your current working directory, while `xargs` will redirect it to `cat` thus instantly printing the content of the file(s) found.

Comment: until the pattern is in a file named `with spaces`...